# Series $\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n}e^{n^{2}z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

Let $$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n}e^{n^{2}z} \ \ \ \ ,z\in \mathbb{C}$$ I want to find the maximal region in which $f$ is holomorphic. I have a problem with the convergence in $\{+i, -i \}$.

Is the series convergent in these $2$ points ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: This answers the question about finding the maximal region of convergence, *although it does not answer the question about convergence at* $\pm i$.

Let $z = x + iy$, let $\alpha = |e^z| = e^x$. Then $|e^{n^2z}| = e^{n^2x} = \alpha^{n^2}$.
Use the ratio test, and get the ratio
$$
\frac{\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}\alpha^{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{z^n}{n}\alpha^{n^2}} = \frac{n}{n+1}z\alpha^{2n+1}
$$
This ratio approaches $0$ when $\alpha < 1$ and diverges to $+\infty$ when $\alpha > 1$.

So the original series converges when the real part is less than zero, and diverges when the real part is greater than zero. You are looking for the largest *region* (open, connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$), so the **answer is the open left half plane**. The imaginary axis is the boundary of the region.